# merge array values - PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays:

First:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Catalog No.:
    [1] => H-B No.
)
```

Second array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => GG
            [1] => 692
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => VV
            [1] => 693
        )

)
```

I want o to merge them into one array to get this:

```
 Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => Catalog No.: GG
                [1] => H-B No. 692
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => Catalog No.: VV
                [1] => H-B No. 693
            )

    )
```

I tried with array merge, but that works with keys and values, I want to merge only values from this two arrays into one, any help?

Comment: There's nothing bulit-in that does this, you have to write a loop.

Comment: You can use nested `foreach` loops or nested `array_map()` functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$first = ['Catalog No.:', 'H-B No.'];
$second = [['GG', 692],['VV', 693]];
$result = [];

foreach ($second as $key => $values) {
    foreach ($values as $number => $value) {
        if (!isset($first[$number])) {
            continue;
        } 

        $result[$key][] = $first[$number] . ' ' . $value;
    }
}

var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way could be using [array_map](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and prepend the values from `$first` to the current `$arr`

```
$result = array_map(function($arr) use ($first){
    foreach($first as $key => $value) {
        $arr[$key] = $value . ' ' . $arr[$key];
    }
    return $arr;
}, $second);
```

[Php demo](https://3v4l.org/NWlnG)